# Rendering 3D scene elements separately before compositing - Is it the right workflow

Tags: 3d, compositing, render

Would it be right to render elements in the scene that I made, in separate EXR image sequences?

What else should I keep in mind to render before moving on to compositing?

Comment: I think you need to go into more detail about what you're making, and what software you're using

Comment: So basically I have a 3d scene extension which is a 3D tunnel running into a live action mountain, on top of this mountain I also placed a chain-linked fence and in the foreground I placed a car. Would it make sense to render these elements out individually so that I can color correct them separately?

Comment: @TORM3NTO yes, you have the right idea, individual elements gives you best control.